# Infinite loop and corrupted files when transfering files from server to client

Tags: loops, sockets, server, tcp, data-transfer

I have a project to do using Sockets. I am able to transfer the data from client to server, but there has to be an error, since I do not close the socket. Is there a way to fix that?

Also, the main issue is when trying to download a file from server. It ends up being corrupted. I also suspect that my program has to be able to work for several file transfers from server to client and the other way around. The socket is already open when initiating a transfer.

Here is the code for download from client (the download option is selected in the client's application, and then processed in the server):

```java
try {
    out.writeUTF(entree);
    final int TEMPS_DE_PAUSE = 5000;
    Thread.sleep(TEMPS_DE_PAUSE);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadPath + "\\" + name));
    BufferedOutputStream outBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    while((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Tentative de telechargement du serveur reussie!");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Une erreur lors de la reception du serveur est survenue...");
}
```

And here is the server part:

```java
try {
    String path = currentPath + "\\" + name;
    /*
     * Source: https://github.com/WittCode/java-send-and-download-a-file/blob/main/Client/src/Client.java
     */
    // S'assurer que la grandeur est assez grande pour des gros fichiers!!!
    File fichierAEnvoyer = null;

    try {
        fichierAEnvoyer = new File(path);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        out.writeUTF("Le fichier n'existe pas! Veuillez entrer son nom de nouveau!");
    }

    out.writeUTF("Tentative de televersement du serveur au client.");

    final short TAILLE_OCTET_MAXIMUM = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[TAILLE_OCTET_MAXIMUM];
    int count;

    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichierAEnvoyer));
    while ((count = input.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
    out.writeUTF("Une erreur est survenue lors du televersement du serveur au client.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help as to why there is an infinite loop will be appreciated.

Also, if there are resources online about the "typical way" of doing file transfers, I am open to consulting them, as I seem to find different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not do anything to indicate to the client when the file transfer is finished, so the client does not know when to stop reading, it just keeps reading until disconnected or errored.

One way to handle this is to have the server send the file size before sending the file bytes, then the client can read the size first and then read the indicated number of bytes.

Comment: Thank you. I found a way around it which isn't as good as the one described but still works fine.